# How do graphql subscriptions work under the hood?

Tags: websocket, graphql, subscription

I know it's usually with websockets, but when I implement subscriptions with say graphql-yoga, I can listen on playground but how can I do that with pure javascript? Like using the javascript's built-in WebSocket class.